# Find string in a file after a string pattern using shell script

Tags: regex, shell

i have my output file with 4 lines

```
storefront/storefront.war/location/header-info.jsp:30:<input type="hidden" id="welcomeConfigValue" value="${welcomeConfig}"/>
storefront/storefront.war/location/header-info.jsp:31:<span id="selected-location" class="top-txt top-nav-fix">
storefront/storefront.war/location/header-info.jsp:33:<span id="headRestName"></span><span class="header-spacing"> | </span><span id="headRestPhone"></span><span class="header-spacing"> | </span>
storefront/storefront.war/location/header-info.jsp:35:<a href="#" class="capitalize link-wht" id="location-show"><fmt:message
```

I'd like to get output string after `id=` with the UNIX shell.

I.e., output should be like this:

```
welcomeConfigValue
selected-location
headRestName
headRestPhone
location-show
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with grep:

```
grep -Po '\sid="\K[^"]*' file
```

Answer (score 0):

**Command:**

```
sed -r 's/(^.*id=")([^"]+)(.*$)/\2/g' < file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ sed -r 's/(^.*id=")([^"]+)(.*$)/\2/g' < ff.txt
welcomeConfigValue
selected-location
headRestPhone
location-show
```

Here, we are grouping the patterns into 3 sets using "(" & ")". First set contains all characters from beginning of the line till 'id="' including. Second set contains characters between the "s (i.e between 'id="' and the pair '"'). Third set contains the remaining chars till the end of the line. Then we just avoid the 1st and 3rd patterns.

Comment: Misses `headRestName`

Comment: tr " " "\n" < ff.txt | grep -E "id=" | sed -r 's/(^.*id=")([^"]+)(.*$)/\2/g'   Not the best solution (with 3 fork/exec), will update better one later!